# Express the cartesian partial derivative in polar coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I do not completely understand what we have done:

Let $\omega$ be a differentiable function of variables $x$ and $y$.

Now we have to express $\omega_x$ and $\omega_y$ with $\omega_r$, $\omega_\phi$, $r$ and $\phi$.

So:

$$\omega_x = \omega_r \cdot r_x + \omega_\phi \cdot \phi_x$$
$$\omega_y = \omega_r \cdot r_y + \omega_\phi \cdot \phi_y$$

So then $\tan{\frac{y}{x}}$ we do partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and to $y$ and we get:

$$\phi_x = - \frac{\sin(\phi)}{r}$$
$$\phi_y = \frac{\cos{\phi}}{r}$$
We do the same with $r_x$, so to apply the partial derivative to $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

However I do not understand how can we differentiate $r$ or $\phi$, since it represents only an angle and the radius. How can we just do that I do not get it.

Comment: "it represents only an angle and a radius"... but, $x$ and $y$ just represent two sides of a triangle, so why should we be able to take derivatives with respect to *them*?  The point is that $x$ and $y$ are one way of representing a point in space, and so are $r$ and $\phi$, and we can then move around in that space by varying those coordinates. Therefore, we can take derivatives with respect to them.

Comment: @march Well I mean, we can do $\omega(x(\phi,r), y(\phi,r))$, but we can't do $\omega(\phi(x,y),r(x,y))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r$ and $\phi$ are a different coordinate system so that any point $(x,y)$ has a unique representation $r(x,y)$, $\phi(x,y)$. Conversely for each $(r,\phi)$ we have $x(r,\phi),y(r,\phi)$. So both can be seen as a function of the other and thus may be differentiated.

It is easier though to do the inverse transformation, since the transformations are prettier:

Let us say $w$ is given in regular coordinates $w=w(x,y)$. Then
$$ w(x,y) = w(r\cos(\phi),r\sin(\phi))$$
So by the chain rule
$$ w_r(r,phi) = w_x(x(r,phi),y(r,\phi))\cos(\phi) + w_y(x(r,phi),y(r,\phi))\sin(\phi)$$
and
$$ w_\phi(r,\phi) = -w_x(x(r,phi),y(r,\phi))r\sin(\phi) + w_y(x(r,phi),y(r,\phi))r\cos(\phi)$$
Now you only need to solve this linear system for $w_x,w_y$.

Comment: Why do we get $\omega_x$ in the second expression, if we partially differentiate by $r$ ?

Comment: Well I mean, we can do $\omega(x(\phi,r), y(\phi,r))$, but we can't do $\omega(\phi(x,y),r(x,y))$

Comment: That is the chain rule for multidimensional functions. If we have $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ and $(g_1,\ldots,g_n)(y_1,\ldots,y_m)$ then $$\frac{d}{dy_i} f(g_1,\ldots, g_n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{df}{dx_k}(g_1,\ldots,g_n)\frac{dg}{dy_i}$$